# One to Many Relationship Case Nested in If Statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, case, nested-loops

I have two tables I am trying to query. Table A includes number of tickets sold, number of tickets scanned, account id, name of the account. Table B includes the account id and the account group membership. Unfortunately the Account Group Membership field has multiple uses (I do not have the ability to change the table structure, third party DB).
I would like to find the Account Group Membership for each line in first table, but only if it shows up in a specific list of account groups and then if none of the account groups are in the list it sends back a not included.

I am thinking a Case inside an If loop? but can't seem to work it out. Here is what I have now (which doesn't work at all)

```
select a.num_seats,
a.num_seats_attended,
a.acct_id,
a.owner_name,
if b.membership_id in (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,740) THEN 
(CASE WHEN b.membership_id = 10 then 'Type A'
when b.membership_id = 11 then 'Type B'
when b.membership_id = 12 then 'Type C'
when b.membership_id = 13 then 'Type D'
when b.membership_id = 14 then 'Type E'
when b.membership_id = 15 then 'Type F'
when b.membership_id = 16 then 'Type G'
when b.membership_id = 17 then 'Type H'
when b.membership_id = 18 then 'Type I'
when b.membership_id = 19 then 'Type J'
when b.membership_id = 20 then 'Type K'
when b.membership_id = 21 then 'Type L'
when b.membership_id = 22 then 'Type M'
when b.membership_id = 23 then 'Type N'
when b.membership_id = 24 then 'Type O'
when b.membership_id = 25 then 'Type P'
when b.membership_id = 740 then 'Type Q')
else 'Non Member'
end as membership_level
from table a, table b
where a.acct_id = b.acct_id

Table A
Num_Seats   Num_Seats_Attended  acct_id owner_name
1           1                   345     J Doe
2           1                   673     M Singh
1           0                   354     T Chong
3           3                   767     F McDonald
1           1                   768     C Macron

Table B
acct_id     membership_id
345         1
345         12
673         208
354         13
767         740
767         82
768         7

With results looking like
Num_Seats   Num_Seats_Attended  acct_id owner_name  membership_level
1           1                   345     J Doe       Type C
2           1                   673     M Singh     Not Included
1           0                   354     T Chong     Type D
3           3                   767     F McDonald  Type Q
1           1                   768     C Macron    Not Included
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use an IF statement inside a query, IF statements are only for use in stored procedures/functions/triggers.  You can use a CASE with a single WHEN instead:

```
case when b.membership_id in (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,740) THEN 
(CASE WHEN b.membership_id = 10 then 'Type A'
when b.membership_id = 11 then 'Type B'
when b.membership_id = 12 then 'Type C'
when b.membership_id = 13 then 'Type D'
when b.membership_id = 14 then 'Type E'
when b.membership_id = 15 then 'Type F'
when b.membership_id = 16 then 'Type G'
when b.membership_id = 17 then 'Type H'
when b.membership_id = 18 then 'Type I'
when b.membership_id = 19 then 'Type J'
when b.membership_id = 20 then 'Type K'
when b.membership_id = 21 then 'Type L'
when b.membership_id = 22 then 'Type M'
when b.membership_id = 23 then 'Type N'
when b.membership_id = 24 then 'Type O'
when b.membership_id = 25 then 'Type P'
when b.membership_id = 740 then 'Type Q' END)
else 'Non Member'
end as membership_level
```

(note that your CASE was missing its END)

Or you can use mysql's nonstandard IF function (IF(testcondition,trueresult,falseresult)):

```
IF(b.membership_id in (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,740), 
(CASE WHEN b.membership_id = 10 then 'Type A'
when b.membership_id = 11 then 'Type B'
when b.membership_id = 12 then 'Type C'
when b.membership_id = 13 then 'Type D'
when b.membership_id = 14 then 'Type E'
when b.membership_id = 15 then 'Type F'
when b.membership_id = 16 then 'Type G'
when b.membership_id = 17 then 'Type H'
when b.membership_id = 18 then 'Type I'
when b.membership_id = 19 then 'Type J'
when b.membership_id = 20 then 'Type K'
when b.membership_id = 21 then 'Type L'
when b.membership_id = 22 then 'Type M'
when b.membership_id = 23 then 'Type N'
when b.membership_id = 24 then 'Type O'
when b.membership_id = 25 then 'Type P'
when b.membership_id = 740 then 'Type Q' END),
'Non Member') as membership_level
```

Or just ditch the `in` and include Non Member in the case:

```
CASE WHEN b.membership_id = 10 then 'Type A'
when b.membership_id = 11 then 'Type B'
when b.membership_id = 12 then 'Type C'
when b.membership_id = 13 then 'Type D'
when b.membership_id = 14 then 'Type E'
when b.membership_id = 15 then 'Type F'
when b.membership_id = 16 then 'Type G'
when b.membership_id = 17 then 'Type H'
when b.membership_id = 18 then 'Type I'
when b.membership_id = 19 then 'Type J'
when b.membership_id = 20 then 'Type K'
when b.membership_id = 21 then 'Type L'
when b.membership_id = 22 then 'Type M'
when b.membership_id = 23 then 'Type N'
when b.membership_id = 24 then 'Type O'
when b.membership_id = 25 then 'Type P'
when b.membership_id = 740 then 'Type Q'
else 'Non Member'
end as membership_level
```

or the terser form:

```
CASE b.membership_id
when 10 then 'Type A'
when 11 then 'Type B'
when 12 then 'Type C'
when 13 then 'Type D'
when 14 then 'Type E'
when 15 then 'Type F'
when 16 then 'Type G'
when 17 then 'Type H'
when 18 then 'Type I'
when 19 then 'Type J'
when 20 then 'Type K'
when 21 then 'Type L'
when 22 then 'Type M'
when 23 then 'Type N'
when 24 then 'Type O'
when 25 then 'Type P'
when 740 then 'Type Q'
else 'Non Member'
end as membership_level
```

or use the (mysql specific I think) ELT and FIELD to do the mapping:

```
coalesce(elt(field(b.membership_id,10,11,12...),'Type A','Type B','Type C'...),'Non Member)
```

To deal with the multiple rows per account issue, I suggest you start by only joining the membership rows you want, and group by acct_id and use max on the membership level to make which of multiple types are returned consistent:

```
select a.num_seats,
a.num_seats_attended,
a.acct_id,
a.owner_name,
max(CASE b.membership_id
when 10 then 'Type A'
when 11 then 'Type B'
when 12 then 'Type C'
when 13 then 'Type D'
when 14 then 'Type E'
when 15 then 'Type F'
when 16 then 'Type G'
when 17 then 'Type H'
when 18 then 'Type I'
when 19 then 'Type J'
when 20 then 'Type K'
when 21 then 'Type L'
when 22 then 'Type M'
when 23 then 'Type N'
when 24 then 'Type O'
when 25 then 'Type P'
when 740 then 'Type Q'
else 'Non Member'
end) as membership_level
from table a
left join table b on b.acct_id = a.acct_id and b.membership_id in (10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,740)
group by a.acct_id
```

Comment: These are all amazing solutions to nesting the case, however, they don't deal with the under lying one to many relationship and return a duplicated from from Table A for every entry in Table B .

Comment: @JulieDunsmuir ah, you don't really express that in your question.  are there ever more than one of the 10,11,...,25,740 types?  if so, do you want more than one row in that case but not an extra row for any other membership_id? or always just one row, in which case which case what do you want returned for membership_level if there's more than one?

Comment: there is a possibility that multiple rows exist within the list of options, but very infrequently, in that case it would be fine to only have one row returned, and insignificant which result the query finds, just don't want a row that has a list match to come up as a not included. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: @JulieDunsmuir added to my answer

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, I either get duplicate (without the join in clause) or only get records with a membership (doesn't account for those not in these groups

Comment: what do you mean by duplicate?  with the group by a.acct_id, it will only ever return one row for each acct_id.  can you edit this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=509e5cb7b687ea7dec70d845bddd0f67 to add data that shows your problem and reply here with the new fiddle link?